# How do I match this regex, so that it does not the exceed the digit limit set by me?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have created a regex to match phone numbers in US format, it reads like

`Pattern.compile("\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?-?\\s?(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})")`, it does its job, but also matches itself with unwanted strings for e.g it returns `231-823-1255` for *103-3231823-1255288* when it actually shouldn't, where Am I going wrong?

And yes I am writing a Java code...

Comment: Please post regexes not strings, so skip the double backslashes. You’re just confusing yourself.  Too complicated. Your pattern is actually `\(?(\d{3}\)?-?\s?(\d{3})-(\d{4})`, which does not make a lot of sense. Why the literal backslash? That not a legal Java pattern because Java does not support conditional patterns.

Comment: I am doing regexes for the first time, the way you comment makes me feel like you invented them, if I am wrong then it is because I am learning it for the first time, and when I learn something then I cannot do wrong forever.

BTW every question asked on Stackoverflow is not homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$` to tie the regex to the end of the string.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a list of what you would like to accept for sure. This would help you get what you really want. You may want to check the phone number start and termination with a whitespace, but its really up to you what to accept and what not.

Comment: And if you don't need to dig-out the phone number from a big String, you can use `^` for start and `$` for end-marker. Also, this could be valuable, I guess: [link](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/)

Answer (score 0):

```
\\b after the digits did the job...
```

i.e. setting a boundary for our string

eg `(\\b\\d{4}\\b)`, thank you Oli Charlesworth...

Comment: That will fail on Unicode, BTW, because Java’s `\b` is broken prior to Java 7.